# EEPROM address definitions and delay

Tags: pic, eeprom

I am using 24LC256 EEPROM which have addresses from 0x0000-0x7fff. But I would like to predefine certain address from EEPROM to specific tasks, like from 0-100 for task-1 and so on.

Does predefining those addresses in the C code work?

Like:

```
const int add[31] =   {0,4,8,12,16,20,24,28,32,36,40};
```

Will it work or should we point address as `0x0000 - 0x7fff`?

And my other question is, how much delay must be done after writing operation (simple write/Page write) in an EEPROM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first is a programming issue and the rest of your code will decide how you want to designate the sections of the device.

For the second, the datasheet gives a maximum of 5ms to program a byte or page, but you can use acknowledge polling to check if the device has completed the operation before that time has elapsed; see section 7.0, "Acknowledge Polling" of the Microchip 24AA256/24LC256/24FC256 datasheet for details.

Comment: So the first case would work i trust.By declaring address locations as numbers instead of hexadecimal

Comment: Oh, is that what that was about? The compiler doesn't care what radix you use for your numbers.

Comment: What would the time needed to read a byte from eeprom?

Comment: No more time than however long it takes to perform the transaction.  The data should be available immediately, it's just a question of how quickly you can get it out of the chip on the bus.

Comment: I have not found any docs regarding the read time from eeprom after it is written on to the chip.Certainly it must be lesser than 5ms i trust

Comment: @Rookie91: Reading from EEPROM is a *much* faster operation than writing, so much so that I2C will be the bottleneck, not the EEPROM.